# Props change on click from the ones during a render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is really weird. I have 2 components. A parent, and a child. They go like this:

Parent:

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(this.props.friend.nickname).on("value", snap => {
        const friend = arrayFromObject(snap.val())[0];
        this.setState({friend});
    });
}

render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    const {friend} = this.state;
    if (!friend) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!friend.friends[user.id]) {
        return null;
    }
    if (friend.friends[user.id].accepted !== true) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div className='friendAdapter floatLeft'>
            <GroupCheckBoxContainer friend={friend}/>
            <div className='friendAvatar'/>
            <div className='friendNick'>{friend.nickname}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child:

```
const {group} = user.friends.find(f => f.userID === friend.id);

return (
    <div>
        {console.log(friend.id)}
        <label htmlFor={'groupCheckBox'} className='checkbox_container'>
            <input className='checkbox_custom' id={'groupCheckBox'} type={'checkbox'} onChange={()=>console.log(friend.id)}
                   checked={group}/>
            <span className='checkmark'/>
        </label>
    </div>
)
```

The problem is when I log the `friend.id` on render, I get:

> FEYgs8c4FIPiguOl131BzCb5V8u2 GroupCheckBoxUI.jsx:21:13
>   lO8ogZ67tyU3GlSE42PivzXpBt63 GroupCheckBoxUI.jsx:21:13

​Which is perfect and what I want. But when I render it inside the onChange method, I get for ***both*** of them:

> FEYgs8c4FIPiguOl131BzCb5V8u2 GroupCheckBoxUI.jsx:23:104

It looks like they always take the later prop. Why is that? They are fine during a render, so why are they different during an onChange?

Update:

Ok this is killing me now. I changed the child to this:

```
export default ({friend, user}) => {

    const {group} = user.friends.find(f => f.userID === friend.id);

    const handleChange = () => {
        console.log(friend.id);
        return null;
        firebase
            .database()
            .ref('Users')
            .child(user.id)
            .child('friends')
            .child(friend.id)
            .child('group')
            .set(!group)
            .then(() => console.log('done'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor={'groupCheckBox'} className='checkbox_container'>
                <input className='checkbox_custom' id={'groupCheckBox'} type={'checkbox'}
                       onChange={handleChange}
                       checked={group}/>
                <span className='checkmark'/>
            </label>
            <span onClick={() => console.log(friend.id)}>{friend.id}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And now, I see this:

[image]

So the objects passed are 100% different. Further. When I run the handleClick method and log the ids on a different HTML element, I get the correct ids!

> lO8ogZ67tyU3GlSE42PivzXpBt63 GroupCheckBoxUI.jsx:31:33
>   FEYgs8c4FIPiguOl131BzCb5V8u2 GroupCheckBoxUI.jsx:31:33

I am just lost now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I did not solve the problem, but I found a way around it. I removed the listener from the input and added it to the span. It's messed up, but it works:

```
return (
    <div>
        <label htmlFor={'groupCheckBox'} className='checkbox_container'>
            <input className='checkbox_custom' id={'groupCheckBox'} type={'checkbox'} checked={group}
                   onChange={() => null}/>
            <span onClick={handleClick} className='checkmark'/>
        </label>
        <span onClick={() => console.log(friend.id)}>{friend.id}</span>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the newly selected option on parent component's state. Pass a prop to trigger a callback in parent component, find the selected friend object and set in state.

In Parent:

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(this.props.friend.nickname).on("value", snap => {
    const friend = arrayFromObject(snap.val())[0];
    this.setState({friend});
  });
}
    
changeFriend = (friendID) => {
  // NOTE: Substitute your friends array data here.
  const friend = YourFriendsArrayData.find(f => f.userID === friend.id);
  this.setState({
    friend
  });
}
    
render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    const {friend} = this.state;
    if (!friend) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!friend.friends[user.id]) {
        return null;
    }
    if (friend.friends[user.id].accepted !== true) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className='friendAdapter floatLeft'>
        <GroupCheckBoxContainer friend={friend} onFriendChanged={this.changeFriend} />
        <div className='friendAvatar'/>
        <div className='friendNick'>{friend.nickname}</div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

In Child:

1. Unless and until you modify `friend` object in parent component, `console.log(friend.id)` will be the same.
2. In the `event.target.value` of the checkbox's onChange, you can get the selected value. Send it back in callback to parent component to trigger state change by finding new friend object.

```
const {group} = user.friends.find(f => f.userID === friend.id);

return (
    <div>
        {console.log(friend.id)}
        <label htmlFor={'groupCheckBox'} className='checkbox_container'>
            <input className='checkbox_custom' id={'groupCheckBox'} type={'checkbox'} onChange={(event)=> this.props.onFriendChanged(event.target.value)}
                   checked={group}/>
            <span className='checkmark'/>
        </label>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I am looping through the friends array. The friend object is right on render, and wrong on the onChange. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: I see that you are passing `friend` as a prop to child component. 1. You are not changing it in parent component's state.
2. you are console.logging friend.id which is the unchanged prop from parent component. So it is wrong in onChange. You should try console.logging event.target.value to see what you are selecting.

Comment: I still don't see why it would have two different values in the same component. Maybe I'm missing something. Also, the parent's `friend` variable is being observed by firebase - I didn't think this would be important, but I'm adding it now, so I don't want to change it in the local state, I want to log the id which, again shows correctly on render, but in the same component, prints out differently onChange. Sorry I probably missed some of this earlier